# Weblogic server installation

Tags: oracle, weblogic-10.x

Please I need assistance installing weblogic server. I wanted to install oracle form and report and in the process of installation I was told to install weblogic server to create a middleware home directory. I went to oracle website to download. I downloaded oracle weblogic server 11gr1(10.3.6) + coherence package installer for 64bit JVM generic because oracle weblogic server 12c does not support oracle form and report. After downloading the weblogic server I extracted the zipped file but to my surprise it is all folders upon folder and files there is no installer to install the weblogic server in graphical mode or is there anything I am not doing right or I don't know. Please help.

Comment: Probably better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you deploying Oracle forms and reports or are you trying to install the development applications for Oracle forms and reports?

Comment: I am trying to install the development application for oracle form and reports. It is the software for oracle form and report I want to install but it requires that have weblogic server installed first before you can install it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the instructions and other details pertaining to install using the generic `.jar` installer

[Instructions & Help](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/doc.1211/e24492/prepare.htm#BABFIDAB)

The generic installer is basically a `jar` file for installing on to any supported system (IBM AIX, Oracle Exadata Servers, SUN Solaris etc.). There are specific install instructions for that.

If you are trying to install it on `Windows` server then you should download the Windows x86 `.exe` version or for Linux the `.bin` version.

Comment: My operation system is windows 64bit that is why I downloaded the one that will be compatible. Or do you think the window x86 version will be compatible with 64bit

Comment: The Windows x86 version is with 32-bit JVM, so I think it should be ok. You can try installing that and then you can address any specific error that you (may) get.